# When to switch from Sandbox to production StoreKit server?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, storekit, appstore-sandbox

I recently submitted an app to iTunes that has in-app purchases. At what specific time should I switch from using the sandbox server to the production server?

Now? Or after it is approved?

I can switch at anytime in my php file on my server.

I looked at the StoreKit documentation, and they do not really make this clear.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found an answer on the StoreKit [FAQ](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#technotes/tn2259/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40009578-CH1-FREQUENTLY_ASKED_QUESTIONS):

> What url should I use to verify my receipt (iOS)?
>
> ```
> Use the sandbox URL https://sandbox.itunes.apple.com/verifyReceipt while testing your application in the sandbox and while your application is in review.
>
> Use the production URL http://buy.itunes.apple.com/verifyReceipt once your application is live in the App Store.
> ```

The only thing I still don't understand is, what if I am not at my computer the moment the app goes live to make the switch?

Comment: Don't set your app to be released automagically. You get an email saying it's approved, switch over the URL and then release the app manually.

Answer (score 2):

More from the FAQ:

Always verify your receipt first with the production URL; proceed to verify with the sandbox URL if you receive a 21007 status code. Following this approach ensures that you do not have to switch between URLs while your application is being tested or reviewed in the sandbox or is live in the App Store.

Note: The 21007 status code indicates that this receipt is a sandbox receipt, but it was sent to the production service for verification.